# Unable to go beyond karyotype command in circos using perl command line application

Tags: circos

I am working on Circos with a objective to create a circos plot. This is my very first attempt. I do not have any coding background.
Currently I am trying to use .txt file already available with the installation, karyotype.human.txt. I am using windows system and using Perl (command line) application to write and run the code.

I believe i have successfully installed the software. I have checked for version and modules too. Until here things seem to be ok.
But I am unable to go any further than this as I get the notification of command not recognized:

```
 C:\Users\hemal\OneDrive\Documents>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Circos\bin
    
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Circos\bin> karyotype = C:\Program Files (x86)\Circos\data\karyotype\karyotype.human.txt
```

output:
'karyotype' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

What's going wrong here? Is there any code I need before 'karyotype' command?